# 1994 Ford Aspire: Different computer for automatic vs manual?

Tags: ford, computer, obd-i

This is a 1994 Ford Aspire (*prior to* OBD II, fortunately). It has a simple 3-speed automatic with no computer controls.  It needs to pass smog, so I can't just gut the emission controls, and my "Check Engine" light needs to work properly because that's inspected.

I want to convert it to manual, and I know how involved that is - change flywheel, transmission brace, CV halfshafts, shifter assembly, console panel (not much of it on this car), brake pedal assembly, instrument cluster (for the upshift light) and probably, certain wiring harnesses.  *I'm expecting all this*.  (fortunately it looks like both transmissions use a common "in neutral" and "in reverse" switch connection, so that may be breezy; the interlocks at the shifter won't be a problem since they're going away.)

My question is, do I need to change the PCM (car computer) also, i.e. **does the PCM for manual use a different part number than the PCM for automatic**?  *The big red Ford factory shop manual is no help*.

Comment: Many cars of this era used the exact same PCM for both standard and automatic, however, there is a soft switch (electronic in the tune) which needs to be set one way or the other (AT v MT). I'm not sure if that is the case with the Aspire, but it very well could be ... IIRC, the Aspire was built for Ford by Kia (well before Hyundai owned the company) during the year you mentioned. Also, PCMs could change part numbers from year to year without any rhyme or reason ... just be aware.

Comment: A thought just came to mind ... if you can find a wrecked/trashed Aspire with a manual tranny, you can probably get everything you need for the swap. I'm not sure, but the Fiesta might be the same exact thing ... it was made by Kia for Ford at the same time as the Aspire.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I think you mean the Ford Festiva, not the Fiesta (similar name, completely different car)..

Comment: @alephzero - You are correct it's the Festiva I was thinking of ... thanks :o) Still, the Festiva might have the same innerds as the Aspire, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah I gathered you meant the Festiva :) Yes, good chance.  Aspires and Festivas are getting scarce at the local picking yards, but I can afford to wait for the right car.

Comment: If it's any consolation, I understand both the Aspire and Festiva were great cars. Cheap and would last far longer than you'd expect an entry level beater to last. Then Kia thought they'd bring their own label to the States and they sucked for many years until Hyundai bought a controlling share of them and turned the brand around. Weird how things work out.